# JLabel mouse event works twice by one click

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, jlabel

It didn't on last version, but on latest version it works twice though I only clicked once.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    ((MouseListener)a).mouseClicked(e);
    ((MouseListener)b).mouseClicked(e);
}
```

The code is from AWTEventMulticaster.class, which is library class. It seems that when I click once, Listener woks twice. But it's odd that listener works twice by one event. Not only this, all of the mouse events have changed to work twice, so all of my codes got ruined. Is there any solution of this?

more information under here. First, The code of my mouselistener.

```
Label1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()//Begin
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                Label1.pointerInfo = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();                    
                Label1.setIsPressed(true);
            }
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                if(Label1.getLocation().y<555 && Label1.getIsCard()==true)
                {                       
                    int cn = Label1.getCardNumX();
                    Label1.setCardNumY(getY(cn));                       
                    Label1.setText(null);
                    String s = "/image/\uBE14\uB85D "+Integer.toString(cn)+"-"+Integer.toString(Label1.getCardNumY())+".png";
                    ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(Game.class.getResource(s));
                    Label1.setImage(im.getImage());
                    Label1.setIcon(setIconScale(im, Label1.getCardNumX(), Label1.getCardNumY(), 'L'));
                    Label1.setIsCard(false);
                }
                else if(Label1.getIsCard()==true)
                {
                    Label1.setBounds(70, 600, 150, 150);
                }
                else if(Label1.getLocation().y>675&&Used[0]!=1)
                {
                    Image I = Label1.getImage();
                    ImageIcon im;
                    if(Label1.getIsFlipped()==true)
                    {
                        BufferedImage i = convertToBufferedImage(I);
                        if(Label1.getRot()%2==1)
                            i= verticalFlip(i);
                        else
                            i = horizontalFlip(i);
                        im = new ImageIcon(i);
                    }
                    else
                        im = new ImageIcon(I);                  
                    im = setIconScale(im, Label1.getCardNumX(), Label1.getCardNumY(), 'L');
                    RotatedIcon i = new RotatedIcon(im, (0 - (Label1.getRot()*(90.0))));
                    Label1.setIcon(i);
                    Label1.setBounds(70, 600, 150, 150);
                }
                else if(Used[0]!=1)
                {
                    Icon r = Label1.getIcon();
                    if(Label1.getIsCard() == false && r!= null && BoardLavel.CheckBlock(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo(), Label1.a, Label1.BlockX, Label1.BlockY))                        
                    {
                        Used[0] = 1;
                        Deck[0] = 0;
                        CheckGreen();
                        Label1.setIcon(null);
                        score = score + 100 * BoardLavel.CheckErase();
                        Score.setText("Score = " + Integer.toString(score));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Image I = Label1.getImage();
                        ImageIcon im;
                        if(Label1.getIsFlipped()==true)
                        {
                            BufferedImage i = convertToBufferedImage(I);
                            if(Label1.getRot()%2==1)
                                i= verticalFlip(i);
                            else
                                i = horizontalFlip(i);
                            im = new ImageIcon(i);
                        }
                        else
                            im = new ImageIcon(I);                  
                        im = setIconScale(im, Label1.getCardNumX(), Label1.getCardNumY(), 'L');
                        RotatedIcon i = new RotatedIcon(im, (0 - (Label1.getRot()*(90.0))));
                        Label1.setIcon(i);
                    }
                }
                Label1.setBounds(70, 600, 150, 150);
                Label1.setIsPressed(false);
            }
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(Label1.isCard==false)
            {if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                Label1.changeIsFlipped();
                }
            else if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
            if(Label1.getIsFlipped()==true)
            {
                Label1.setIsRotated(-1);
            }
            else
                Label1.setIsRotated(1);
            }
            Image image = Label1.getImage();
            ImageIcon ima;
            if(Label1.getIsFlipped()==true)
            {
                BufferedImage im = convertToBufferedImage(image);
                if(Label1.getRot()%2==1)
                    im = verticalFlip(im);
                else
                    im = horizontalFlip(im);
                ima = new ImageIcon(im);
            }
            else
                ima = new ImageIcon(image);
            ima = setIconScale(ima, Label1.getCardNumX(), Label1.getCardNumY(), 'L');
            RotatedIcon i = new RotatedIcon(ima, (0 - (Label1.getRot()*(90.0))));
            Label1.setIcon(i);
            }
        }
    });
```

Second, The Fuctions used on Listner.

```
protected void CheckGreen() {
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
            if(BoardLavel.Board[i][j]==1)
            {
                switch(i)
                {
                case 0:
                {
                    switch(j)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        BoardLabel6_0.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        BoardLabel6_1.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BoardLabel6_2.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BoardLabel6_3.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        BoardLabel6_4.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        BoardLabel6_5.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        BoardLabel6_6.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 1:
                {
                    switch(j)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        BoardLabel5_0.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        BoardLabel5_1.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BoardLabel5_2.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BoardLabel5_3.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        BoardLabel5_4.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        BoardLabel5_5.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        BoardLabel5_6.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 2:
                {
                    switch(j)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        BoardLabel4_0.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        BoardLabel4_1.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BoardLabel4_2.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BoardLabel4_3.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        BoardLabel4_4.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        BoardLabel4_5.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        BoardLabel4_6.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 3:
                {
                    switch(j)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        BoardLabel3_0.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        BoardLabel3_1.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BoardLabel3_2.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BoardLabel3_3.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        BoardLabel3_4.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        BoardLabel3_5.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        BoardLabel3_6.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 4:
                {
                    switch(j)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        BoardLabel2_0.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        BoardLabel2_1.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BoardLabel2_2.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BoardLabel2_3.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        BoardLabel2_4.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        BoardLabel2_5.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        BoardLabel2_6.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 5:
                {
                    switch(j)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        BoardLabel1_0.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        BoardLabel1_1.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BoardLabel1_2.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BoardLabel1_3.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        BoardLabel1_4.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        BoardLabel1_5.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        BoardLabel1_6.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 6:
                {
                    switch(j)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        BoardLabel0_0.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        BoardLabel0_1.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BoardLabel0_2.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BoardLabel0_3.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        BoardLabel0_4.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        BoardLabel0_5.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        BoardLabel0_6.setIcon(GreenBoardimg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
}
protected RotatedIcon rotate(Icon icon)
{
    RotatedIcon rot = new RotatedIcon(icon, -90);
    return rot;
}
protected Image RescaledBlock(ImageIcon icon, int x, int y)
{
    Image origin = icon.getImage();
    Image chan= origin.getScaledInstance(x, y, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH );
    return chan;
}
public static BufferedImage horizontalFlip(BufferedImage img) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    BufferedImage flippedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getType());
    Graphics2D g = flippedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, w, 0, 0, h, null);
    g.dispose();
    return flippedImage;
}
public static BufferedImage convertToBufferedImage(Image image)
{
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
        image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return newImage;
}
public static BufferedImage verticalFlip(BufferedImage img) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    BufferedImage flippedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getColorModel().getTransparency());
    Graphics2D g = flippedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, 0, h, w, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return flippedImage;
}
public ImageIcon setIconScale(ImageIcon i, int x, int y, char ch)
{
    ImageIcon im = i;
    if(x==1)
    {
        if(ch=='s')
            im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 20, 20));
        else
            im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 50, 50));
    }
    if(x==2)
    {
        if(y==0)
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 40, 20));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 100, 50));
        }
        else
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 40, 40));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 100, 100));
        }
    }
    if(x==3)
    {
        if(y==0)
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 60, 20));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 150, 50));
        }
        else if(y==1)
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 40, 40));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 100, 100));
        }
        else if(y==2)
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 60, 60));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 150, 150));
        }
        else
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 60, 40));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 150, 100));
        }
    }
    if(x==4)
    {
        if(y==0)
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 40, 40));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 100, 100));
        }
        else if(y==1||y==2||y==3||y==6)
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 60, 40));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 150, 100));
        }
        else
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 60, 60));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 150, 150));
        }
    }
    if(x==5)
    {
        if(y==3)
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 60, 40));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 150, 100));
        }
        else if(y==7)
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 40, 60));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 100, 150));
        }
        else
        {
            if(ch=='s')
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 60, 60));
            else
                im = new ImageIcon(RescaledBlock(im, 150, 150));
        }
    }
    return im;
}
public int getY(int cn)
{
    Random ra = new Random();
    int a = 0;
    switch(cn)
    {
    case 1:
        a =  0;
        break;
    case 2:
        a = ra.nextInt(2);
        break;
    case 3:
        a = ra.nextInt(5);
        break;
    case 4:
        a = ra.nextInt(12);
        break;
    case 5:
        a = ra.nextInt(17);
        break;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Third, the RotatedIcon Class found on here;

https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/

If you need more information, please comment here.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? Is it correct to cast them to a `MouseListener`? You could read [some nice tutorial about *how to write a `MouseListener`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Comment: @deHaar  I found something weird. On first time I clicked, It moved to Component.class, but after few steps I clicked, it moves to AWTEventMulticaster.class. Well, I'll need to read what you recommended, first.

Comment: @deHaar And, I don't know what are a and b means. I'm almost noob on here... :(

Comment: *What are `a` and `b`* means what type have the variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: @deHaar Maybe Somewhat EventListener, I think. When I clicked Label just once, it went to AWTEventMulticaster.class, and what I know is nomally it needed to go to the Component.class.

Comment: Well, a reason for having behaviour occurring twice might be fact that `mouseClicked` is an event consisting of `mousePressed` **and** `mouseReleased` which you are implementing as well. That means both events are handled twice. See [the JavaDocs of `MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-). Comment out your implementation of `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` and try again.

Comment: @deHaar So, you means, whenever I clicked, mousePressed and mouseReleased also worked together, handled to multi event. But that doesn't explain why it doesn't comes out from the very first time, though...